# Parallelogram Inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, quadrilateral, triangle-inequality

Let M be a point inside parallelogram ABCD. Then prove that $MA + MB + MC + MD < 2(AB + BC)$

> I tried this problem using Triangle Inequality but couldn't proceed. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $PP'$ be parallel to $BC$ and $QQ'$ parallel to $AB$, both through $M$. Note that you can apply the triangle inequality to $AM$, $AP'$ and $MP'$. Same for others.

[image: Parallelogram]

Comment: thanks a ton :D